# Как рассчитать кол-во клиентов в python имея текстовый файл с данными?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть текстовый файл с почтами клиентов.
Нужно из данного файла вычленить кол-во клиентов мужчин и женщин.
Для добавления пола заказчика использовал код:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(fpaht + 'email.rcv.csv')
df1['email'] = df1['email'].astype('string')

def get_gender(smth):
b = smth.split('@')[0][-3 : -2]
if b == 'v':
    Gender = 'Мужчина'
else:
    Gender = 'Женщина'
return Gender

df1['Пол заказчика'] = df1.apply(lambda x:get_gender(x['email']), axis = 1)
```

На выходе получается таблица:

```
    email   Пол заказчика
0   savelev73@rambler.ru    Мужчина
1   surkova84@rambler.ru    Женщина
2   petrova87@gmail.com Женщина
3   ryabinina95@rambler.ru  Женщина
4   petrov75@mail.ru    Мужчина
... ... ...
69  cvetkova83@gmail.com    Женщина
70  antonova96@rambler.ru   Женщина
71  aksenov70@rambler.ru    Мужчина
72  vasilev99@yandex.ru Мужчина
73  malysheva96@yandex.ru   Женщина
```

Теперь задача создать таблицу в которой будет 2 столбца:

```
"Пол заказчика"   Кол-во клиентов
"Мужчина"         Х
"Женщина"         Y
```

Умом понимаю, что нужна функция count, но как ее прописать не понимаю

Comment: сгруппируйте по полу и натравите count чтобы получить размер группы

Comment: `df1['Пол заказчика'].value_counts()`, ну или через `groupby` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: Всем спасибо. Оба варианта рабочие. Вариант с groupby удобнее.

Comment: А если в дальнейшем необходимо разделить отдельно два DF на мужчин и женщин, как это лучше сделать?

Comment: странные вопросы для человека, сумевшего написать лямбда-функцию для "определения пола". для выборки используйте метод `.loc`, например.